# How can I get unique values from a list when I use loop and condition

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to create a table where Item Code is main row and Challan No. Is sub row. For every item Item Code is only one and Challan No. is only one. But same Challan No. are allowed for different Item Code.

```
item_table = [('I-101', 'Wall Tiles'), ('I-102', 'Floor Tiles'), ('I-103', 'Wall Tiles')]
in_table = [('I-101', 'C-1415', 100.0), ('I-102', 'C-1469', 110.0), ('I-103', 'C-1455', 120.0), ('I-101', 'C-1897', 130.0), ('I-101', 'C-1415', 140.0), ('I-102', 'C-1415', 150.0), ('I-103', 'C-1897', 160.0)]
out_table = [('I-101', 'C-1415', -100.0), ('I-103', 'C-1455', -500.0)]
for elem in item_table:
    print(elem[0])
    for bill in in_table:
        if elem[0] == bill[0]:
            print(bill[1])
```

This is my problem

[image: This is my problem]

this is my main design

[image: this is my main design]

Comment: You have `('I-101', 'C-1415', 100.0)` and `('I-101', 'C-1415', 140.0)` in `in_table`, so they both get printed. What should it do instead?

Comment: Why is the line unexpected? You are comparing `elem[0] == 'I-101'` to `bill[0] == 'I-101'` for the first item from `in_table`: `('I-101', 'C-1415', 100.0)`.

Comment: Here unexpected is serial no. 4 (C-1415) in given picture.  For every item, Item Code is only one and Challan No. is only one. But my first Code same Challan number are two.  I wanted to avoid serial no. 4 in given picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a set of all the challan numbers that have been printed, so you don't print duplicates.

```
item_table = [('I-101', 'Wall Tiles'), ('I-102', 'Floor Tiles'), ('I-103', 'Wall Tiles')]
in_table = [('I-101', 'C-1415', 100.0), ('I-102', 'C-1469', 110.0), ('I-103', 'C-1455', 120.0), ('I-101', 'C-1897', 130.0), ('I-101', 'C-1415', 140.0), ('I-102', 'C-1415', 150.0), ('I-103', 'C-1897', 160.0)]
out_table = [('I-101', 'C-1415', -100.0), ('I-103', 'C-1455', -500.0)]
for elem in item_table:
    printed = set()
    print(elem[0])
    for bill in in_table:
        if elem[0] == bill[0] and bill[1] not in printed:
            print(bill[1])
            printed.add(bill[1])
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/ltuSZD)

Comment: My unexpected result is serial no. 4 (C-1415) in given picture. My exception is here:           I-101
C-1415
C-1897
I-102
C-1469
C-1415
I-103
C-1455
C-1897

Comment: Do you still get that with my answer?

Comment: I added a working demo that shows that you don't get the unexpected result.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, you full fill my expection. I get my answer.

Comment: Yes, I get my answer!